# "Creation of a TradingView Indicator for Monthly Long or Short Positions Based on the First Four Trading Days

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, trading, pine-script-v4

I would like to have an indicator that recommends a long or short position after the first four trading days. If the return is positive within the first four trading days, then a long position should be taken. If it is negative, then a short position. This position should be held until the end of the month, and then the process starts over!

```
//@version=5
strategy("Monatsanfangsstrategie", shorttitle="MA-Strategie", overlay=true)

// Hilfsfunktion, um den letzten Tag eines Monats zu ermitteln
GetLastDayOfMonth(t) =>
    if (month(t) == 1) or (month(t) == 3) or (month(t) == 5) or (month(t) == 7) or (month(t) == 8) or (month(t) == 10) or (month(t) == 12)
        31
    else if (month(t) == 4) or (month(t) == 6) or (month(t) == 9) or (month(t) == 11)
        30
    else
        year(t) % 4 == 0 and (year(t) % 100 != 0 or year(t) % 400 == 0) ? 29 : 28  // Februar

// Überprüfen, ob der aktuelle Tag der erste Handelstag des Monats ist
IsFirstTradingDayOfMonth() =>
    dayofmonth(time[1]) > dayofmonth(time) or month(time[1]) != month(time)

// Überprüfen, ob der aktuelle Tag der letzte Handelstag des Monats ist
IsLastTradingDayOfMonth() =>
    dayofmonth(time) == GetLastDayOfMonth(time)

// Variablen für die Logik
var float firstPrice = na
var int tradeDirection = 0 // 1 für Long, -1 für Short, 0 für keine Position
var bool tradeInitiated = false

// Preis am ersten Handelstag des Monats festlegen
if IsFirstTradingDayOfMonth()
    firstPrice := close
    tradeDirection := 0
    tradeInitiated := false

// Performance nach den ersten 4 Tagen überprüfen
if dayofmonth(time) == 5 and not tradeInitiated
    if close > firstPrice
        tradeDirection := 1
    else
        tradeDirection := -1
    tradeInitiated := true

// Handel basierend auf der ermittelten Richtung
if tradeDirection != 0 and not IsLastTradingDayOfMonth()
    if tradeDirection == 1
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    else
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

// Position am Ende des Monats schließen
if IsLastTradingDayOfMonth()
    strategy.close_all()
```